# The requested URL /receipt was not found on this server but working on localhost

Tags: vue.js

On localhost, the url works fine but when I publish and try it shows Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Here is the code.

```
      {
        path: "/receipt",
        name: "receipt",
        component: PrintReceipt,
      }
```

This is how I call the router

```
localStorage['params'] = JSON.stringify({
          receiptNo: this.receiptNo
        })
        const routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'receipt'});
        window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

So on localhost its working well but after building and publishing on the server it bring the error not found.

Answer (score 0):

I changed createWebHistory to createWebHashHistory and it worked.

```
import { createWebHashHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";


const router = createRouter({
        history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
});
```